# how to make the models caseinsensitive

Tags: django-models

I have a model.

class Exam(models.Model):
    Examname = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=255)

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.Examname = self.Examname.lower()
    return super(Exam, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Meta:
    unique_together = ["Examname"]    

def __str__(self):
    return self.Examname
```

Examname must be case insensitive in order to avoid the duplicate data. I converted all to small letters and stored. But it is not detecting the duplicate data. for example if i insert External as Examname it is storing as external but other name if i give as external then only it detects as dulicate data. External or eXternal or any atleast one capital letter is there it is not detecting as duplicate data but stored as small letters

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if `regno` should store numbers as well as characters, do not use `FloatField` but for example `CharField`

If you want avoid case sensitivity issues, you may want for example decide to always store values low case when saving your object as follow:

```py
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.regno = self.regno.lower()
        super(Show, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

---

If you need to preserve case, the alternative option would be to duplicate lowcase content in a secondary `CharField`. Which can be automated in the save method.

If you try to insert a duplicate value, django will throw an `IntegrityError`, which should be handled.

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    mytextfield = models.CharField()
    lowcase_textfield = models.CharField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.lowcase_textfield = self.mytextfield.lower()
        try:
            super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        except IntegrityError as e:
            # INSERT YOUR EXCEPTION HANDLING HERE
            pass
```

Comment: I tried it by adding the data to model from admin page but not converting into small letters

Comment: Could you update your question with what you tried to achieve so we can better understand. Have you added the save function in the Show model?

Comment: class Exam(models.Model):
    Examname = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=255)       
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.regno = self.Examname.lower()
        return super(Exam, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Examname

Comment: Edit your question instead of posting your class in a comment, this will be more readable. I am a bit confused, regno seems to belong to the Show model but you seem to have overridden the save method of Exam. Please clarify your question.

Comment: But unique_together is working only for lowercase letters. How to make case insensitive unique model.

Comment: If your db backend is postgres, you could consider https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#citext-fields

Comment: mine is not postgress. can u pls tell any other way

Comment: Two options: 1. If you don't care about the case, convert all to lowcase, as per my example. 2. If you need to preserve the case, create a secondary CharField in which you will copy the lowcase string at save. Then add the unique constraint on this secondary field.

Comment: I tried 1but doesn't works. the code is class Exam(models.Model):
    Examname = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=255)        
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.Examname = self.Examname.lower()
        return super(Exam, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["Examname"]
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Examname

Comment: As already requested, please update your question instead of pasting blobs of code in comments. It's not readable.